# A UIImageView animation was stopped by something

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I create a UIImageView with animationImages.
Like this : 
[The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUoef.jpg)

The imageView execute perfectly most time。But when I show a custom view which poped up using facebook's pop animation in common rootView,the imageView animation would be stopped. I do not konw is this wrong has something about pop.Does anybody can give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

First , the animation of images may ends while the popup is presented so setting **animationRepeatCount** to zero makes it loop again when it reaches final image

```
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
```

Second you may start the animation again in viewDidAppear method

```
 -(void) viewDidAppear
 { 
   [self.imageView startAnimating];
 }
```

Finally it's better to declare the imageView

```
var imageView:UIImageview!
```

out of viewDidLoad

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.